# What programming languages are supported by XFCE plugins?

Tags: xfce

What programming languages are supported by XFCE plugins? \

Comment: From what I've seen you can only write these plugins in C (maybe in C++ too, but I'm not sure).

Comment: @luke1985 I have seen python and C so far. I need a full list, not guesses.

Comment: That's why I've posted a comment; other than that you will have to wait for an answer. I guess you would get the answer yourself if you look at the project sources.

Comment: @luke1985 That's my problem, I'd like to know this from some kind of documentation, not from the source code. Isn't there a plugin api docs? I did not find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce)

> Xfce is based on the GTK+ toolkit.

See [gtk.org/language-bindings](https://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php).

Next, you can search for this:

> Together with GtkSocket, GtkPlug provides the ability to embed widgets from one process into another process in a fashion that is transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: Cleaned up answer a bit and linked to complete GTK+ language binding support (again).*

---

### **GTK Language Binding Support:**

**As answered earlier, Xfce is GTK+ and uses that toolkit.**

https://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php

---

### **Panel Plugins:**

**Creating a panel plugin:**

Python is supported, along with what GTK+ uses. Whisker (the panel plugin) uses Python, and I believe Orage does as well.

https://wiki.xfce.org/dev/howto/panel_plugins